# cakephp and containable behaviour

Tags: php, sql, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have the following json:

```
{
   "Companies":[
      {
         "CompanyPersonTask":{
            "company_id":"502d1844-3638-44dc-824c-14f02e0cc009",
            "person_id":"2",
            "task_id":"1"
         },
         "Company":{
            "id":"502d1844-3638-44dc-824c-14f02e0cc009",
            "name":"mostro",
            "Office":[
               {
                  "id":"502d1844-b90c-44f5-84c5-14f02e0cc009",
                  "company_id":"502d1844-3638-44dc-824c-14f02e0cc009",
                  "region":"Emilia-Romagna",
                  "city":"Rozzemilia",
                  "address":"-",
                  "phone":"-",
                  "legal_office":true
               }
            ],
            "CompanyPersonTask":[
               {
                  "company_id":"502d1844-3638-44dc-824c-14f02e0cc009",
                  "person_id":"2",
                  "task_id":"1"
               }
            ]
         },
         "Person":{
            "id":"2",
            "first_name":"Carlo",
            "last_name":"Giusti",
            "home_address":"Russi",
            "job_address":null,
            "phone":null,
            "fax":null,
            "mail":null,
            "full_name":"Giusti Carlo",
            "OfficePersonTask":[

            ],
            "CompanyPersonTask":[
               {
                  "company_id":"502d1844-3638-44dc-824c-14f02e0cc009",
                  "person_id":"2",
                  "task_id":"1"
               }
            ]
         },
         "Task":{
            "id":"1",
            "short_name":"Proprietario",
            "full_name":null,
            "info":null,
            "OfficePersonTask":[

            ],
            "CompanyPersonTask":[
               {
                  "company_id":"502d1844-3638-44dc-824c-14f02e0cc009",
                  "person_id":"2",
                  "task_id":"1"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

That is created by this method, inside CompanyPersonTask model:

```
public function getCompaniesByRegion($region){
    $this->recursive = 2;
    return $this->find('all');   
}
```

but I want my json to be formatted like this:

```
{
   "Companies":[
      {
         "Company":{
            "id":"502d1844-3638-44dc-824c-14f02e0cc009",
            "name":"mostro",
            "Office":[
               {
                  "id":"502d1844-b90c-44f5-84c5-14f02e0cc009",
                  "company_id":"502d1844-3638-44dc-824c-14f02e0cc009",
                  "region":"Emilia-Romagna",
                  "city":"Rozzemilia",
                  "address":"-",
                  "phone":"-",
                  "legal_office":true
               }
            ]
         },
         "Person":{
            "id":"2",
            "first_name":"Carlo",
            "last_name":"Giusti",
            "home_address":"Russi",
            "job_address":null,
            "phone":null,
            "fax":null,
            "mail":null,
            "full_name":"Giusti Carlo"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I modify my method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Containable behavior to filter result data.
For more explanation refer [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `unbindModel` in cake php to remove the relation on the fly. This will prevent the data from the unwanted table. [Check this.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

```
<?php
$this->Model->unbindModel(
    array('associationType' => array('associatedModelClassName'))
);
```

Comment: The only model that I could unbind is CompanyPersonTask, i.e. the model that define that method...